# AWS DocumentDb indexing for dynamic key value column

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-documentdb, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

Is there any way to implement dynamic key value type data indexing in AWS dynamodb?
e.g.
Some documents may have key-values as
"Key1"-> "value1"
other may have
"key2"-> "value2"
and so on.

I would like to search on these key values efficiently using indexing. In short I am looking for Wildcard indexing feature like CosmosDb where it indexes every property.

If not with AWS DocumentDb, any AWS database recommendations for this type of problem statement?

Comment: Using dynamic values as field names introduces unnecessary complexity to querying. You may consider refactoring the schema to kv tuples like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/H4CHoJ1mbrQ). If schema refactoring is not an option, from my opinion your best bet could be moving to MongoDB as they support [wildcard index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/indexes/index-types/index-wildcard/)